# Custom Icon for custom mule connector development

Tags: mule, devkit

I need to change default  icon of my custom connector. I tried @icon but it is not supported to 308 version. But it is getting imported for 3.6 Version. So, How can I change icon in mule 3.8.

Answer (score 1):

In the package explorer there is a folder called Icons and please replace the icon image file to your file with the same resolution. if you need more details please free ask me  thank you

Comment: I have replaced my image files with them with same name and resolution. But it is considering default icon only.After installing connector, Icon inside target/generated-source/mule/project/icon is generated as default image. Any more change is required. @shankar

Answer (score 0):

This work for me, create folder "theme.classic" and/or "theme.light" in your icon folder with your image icons, then install or update your connector.

Answer (score 0):

To set icon to Mule connector,

In Src/main/Java make a folder call "icons".
in the icons folder make two new folder called "theme.classic", "theme.light". place images in both folder named- "google-maps-connector-large.png", "google-maps-connector-small.png".

And install/Update that connector project.
Connector should have your icons on them.

Comment: The folder is called "icon"